# Loosing data with Primefaces, Google Spreadsheet API and JSF

Tags: netbeans, jsf-2, primefaces, google-sheets-api

Need Help:

I have this code in an xhtml file:

```
<h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
        <h3 style="margin-top:0">Comissió</h3>
        <p:tabView >
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{panelInicial.onTabChange}" update=":form:msgs"/>
            <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{panelInicial.onTabClose}" update=":form:msgs"/>
            <c:forEach items="#{proceso.nomhojas}" var="item-hoja">
                <p:tab title="#{item-hoja}">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
                         <h:outputText
                             value="#{item-hoja}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:tab>
            </c:forEach> 
        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
```

And I have a class with a constructor like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Proceso {
    private String USERNAME = "aaaaa@bbb.com";
    private String PASSWORD= "xxxxxxx";
    private SpreadsheetService service= new     SpreadsheetService("MySpreadsheetIntegration-v1");   
    private List<WorksheetEntry> worksheets;   
    private List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets;
    private SpreadsheetFeed feed;
    private SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet;
    private URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL;
    private String [] Nomhojas;

    public  Proceso()  throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {
   pruebas();
    }
```

With this method in the class:

```
public void pruebas () throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {
   service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

   setSPREADSHEET_FEED_URL(new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full"));    

    setFeed(service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class)) ;
    setSpreadsheets(feed.getEntries());

    int a=0;
    setSpreadsheet(spreadsheets.get(a));
    while (!(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText().equals("COMISSIÓ.xlsx"))){
        setSpreadsheet(spreadsheets.get(a++));
    }

    setWorksheets(spreadsheet.getWorksheets()) ;
    Nomhojas = new String[worksheets.size()];
    String [] Nomhojas2 =new String[worksheets.size()];
        //for (WorksheetEntry worksheet : worksheets) {
        for (int i=0;i<Nomhojas.length;i++){
           // Nomhojas.add(worksheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
            Nomhojas2[i]=worksheets.get(i).getTitle().getPlainText();            
        }
        setNomhojas(Nomhojas2);

}
```

The result is a Tabview with 8 tabs (corresponding to the 8 worksheets) with the text: "0". 
However, i tried it in a desktop application (no web) and the result is an String array with 8 entries but with its corresponding text in each one (not text "0").

In web results i lost the content of the string.
Thanks

Comment: Strange that it gets the right number of worksheets, but a title of "0". ... Err, different topic, your while loop looks to be missing an a++

Comment: Correct, a++, modified, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using tabView owner iterator instead of c:forEach and adding this to web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>   
</context-param>
```